# Django - DRF (django-rest-framework-social-oauth2) and React creating a user

Tags: django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, python-social-auth

I'm using the DRF and ReactJS and I am trying to login with Patreon using 
`django-rest-framework-social-oauth2`.

In React, I send a request to the back-end `auth/login/patreon/` and I reach the Patreon OAuth screen where I say I want to login with PAtreon. Patreon then returns with a request to the back-end at `accounts/profile`. At this point a `python-social-oauth` user has also been created.

At this point I'm confused. How do I make a request to Patreon to login, create a user in the back-end, and return the session information to the react front-end so that I can include the session information in all following requests from the front-end? I don't want the returned request to be at the backend`/accounts/profile`, do I?

**Update**
I now realize I can set the redirect url with `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` but still, how do I now retrieve the session id, pass it to the front-end, and include it with all requests?

Answer (score 0):

Once you receive the user profile `email`, `unique id`, and other details from Patreon then create a user at the Database level.

Now after creating a user at the Database level you have to log in the user using the Django login function or any other login mechanism before redirecting the user to the frontend with a session.  The redirect URL  for the home/ landing page is provided by the Frontend side where they want to land the user after being successfully logged with session-id being set in cookies. Onward Frontend side can use session id in cookies for other requests.

**Here is the flow:**

> React JS -> auth/login/patreon/ -> redirected to Patreon -> Redirected back to the Backend with  user information -> Create User (DB level) -> Login user  -> Redirect back to Frontend (React JS on a specific URL provided by Front end)

Comment: That means react app should be 'started' again? (Losing state)